# "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.": Problem between class "cta-author" and cline?

Tags: pdftex, cline

There seems to be a problem between cta-author class and cline. Here is my MWE giving me back "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.":

```
    \documentclass{cta-author}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{table*}[h]
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
          What & the & * ? \\
          \cline{2-3} 
          0 & 1 & 2
        \end{tabular}
      \end{table*}
    \end{document}
```

cta-author.cls can be found in the current version of the IET Journal template -> http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_ResearchJournals_latex.zip

Any idea how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer with the `hhline` package:

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table*}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      What & the & * ? \\\hhline{~--}
      0 & 1 & 2
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

In the arguments of `\hhline` you can specify the separator line for each column. `~`  stands for no line, and `-` stands for single line.
See also [the documentation](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/table/hhline.pdf).

[image]

Comment: This solution did not inflate the table like the cmidrule from bookstabs, which seems to insert some extra vertical space.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `booktabs` package, you can use `\cmidrule` instead of `\cline`.

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table*}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      What & the & * ? \\\cmidrule{2-3}
      0 & 1 & 2
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]